# Can I recover wallet seed from overwritten Tails OS USB?

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, tails-os

I've had Tails OS installed on a USB drive for a couple of years. This summer an update made it unable to boot. I installed a fresh Tails OS after formatting the drive, and then realised that I never written the seed to my crypto wallet outside of Tails (I should have known better, I know).

I'm not very experienced with data recovery tools, but I believe I can recover the wallet with some guidance, but I can't find anything online that has helped yet.

I don't know if this is even possible, but I will offer a reward to anyone who's able to help me recover the wallet.
Thanks!

Comment: Update: So far I was able to use ddrescue to read the current files on the OS. This is however now what i need... as I could access them already from inside the Tails OS. Does anyone have any suggestions on what tools might uncover the files on the old install? As far as I know they should still exist, and all I need to rescue is 1 text file with the wallet seed.

Comment: Tails uses two partitions: One for the OS, and one for the encrypted data persistence. If you are lucky your LUKS partition is still there, so you would have to construct a partition table that allows addressing it. See tools for "recover lost LUKS partition".